# Pasar Proyecto Java JSP de JDK 11.0.7 A JDK 14.1

Tags: java, jsp

tengo un proyecto en java jsp con jdk 11.0.7 corriendo sobre payara server, hasta ahora me entero que el jdk 11 es pago es recomendable usar jdk 14 para cambiar de jdk ya que esta version no es paga ??

Answer (score 1):

Realmente todos los JDK pertenecientes a `Oracle` pasado un periodo o versión se convierten de pago, si lo que quieres es mantener una versión libre y sin problemas de actualizaciónes de bugs y seguridad te recomiendo la `JDK` del proyecto `AdoptOpenJDK` que se encarga de garantizar que tengas actualizaciones probadas y continuas de la implementación de referencia `OpenJDK`.

Hay que tener en cuenta que desde ese movimiento de parte de Oracle con la `JDK 8 versión 212+ y JDK 11+` para ser de pago libero el conjunto de pruebas que es lo que te permite certificar la JDK por lo que actualmente la compatibilidad obtenida por `OpenJDK` prácticamente es la misma que la Oficial de Oracle, con estos test se pueden crear nuevas implementaciones y certificar la compatibilidad de las JDK de terceros algo que no era posible en el pasado, incluso ahora `OpenJDK` es la implementación de referencia para las nuevas características.

Otras implementaciones gratuitas de la JDK son: `Eclipse OpenJ9`, `Amazon Coretton`, `GraalVM`  esta ultima trae una propuesta bastante innovadora al mundo de Java  como la compilación del código java a nativo pero aun no es muy estable y no funciona con todos los frameworks por ejemplo Spring.

https://adoptopenjdk.net/